# How to access object outside of class

Tags: php, class, object

I'm trying to access an object outside of a class. I already have a class called Database which has a series of functions in it.

```
$database = new Database($host,$user,$pass,$name);

class User {

    function view($username) {
        $user = $database->findFirst('User','username',$username);
    }
}
```

I cannot work out how to access the $database object and keep getting an error saying Undefined variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of dependnecy injection - constructor injection, e.g.

```
class User
{

    /**
     * @var Database
     */
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Database $database)
    {
        $this->db = $database;
    }

    public function view($username)
    {
        $user = $this->db->findFirst('User', 'username', $username);
    }
}


$database = new Database(/* ... */);
$user = new User($database);
```

**Regarding the question in comment:** Yes, this is possible. Let's think about some basic (abstract) class that could be used as a parent for all classes that should share the same basic logic (e.g. connecting to a DB, or at least injecting a DB connection).

Such abstract class could be:

```
class DBObject
{

    /**
     * @var Database
     */
    protected $db;

    public function __construct(Database $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}
```

Then our `User` class can extend this abstract class in this way:

```
class User extends DBObject
{

    public function view($username)
    {
        $user = $this->db->findFirst('User', 'username', $username);
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that though the abstract class can implement `__construct()` function, it cannot be directly instantiated. Then somewhere in the code You can do the very same as in first example:

```
$database = new Database(/* ... */);
$user = new User($database);
$post = new Post($database);
```

Comment: Is there any way to do dependency injection to say, a Main class and then extend the User class from that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what You mean... Could you be more specific?

Comment: So for example say I have a user class, a posts class, a pages class etc that need to access the database class. Is there any way to make an "umbrella" class so that I can extend the other classes off of that so they have access to the database instead of constructing the database object in each one seperately?

Comment: Thanks for your really quick responses. I've tried as you have explained, but for some reason I am still getting Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context.

Comment: I should also point out that error is in regards to $this->db = $db in the DBObject class.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake... In abstract class when in constructor You have no access to `$this`. I have changed the `abstract class` to just `class`. Also the `$db` property has to be decvlared as `protected`.

Comment: The same fatal error is coming up regarding calling $this->database from the User class. Very strange, as far as I can see everything seems correct.

Answer (score 1):

`$database` should be a class member. Try this:

```
$database = new Database($host,$user,$pass,$name);

class User {
    protected $db;
   public function __construct($database) {

        $this->db = $database;
    }
    public function view($username) {

        $user = $db->findFirst('User','username',$username);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply define it as global variable within the function. Yet the proper way would be to make constructors or *extend* it with **Database** class.

```
 $database = new Database($host,$user,$pass,$name);

    class User {

        function view($username) {
            global $database;
            $user = $database->findFirst('User','username',$username);
        }
    }
```

P.S. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415577/accessing-variables-and-methods-outside-of-class-definitions) is another post where you can see the same situation with this solution.

Comment: Keyword `global` was introduced in PHP4 as should also stay only in PHP4. In PHP5 there are is much better OO implemented allowing also better OO approaches...

Comment: And what do you mean by *extend it with Database class*? Can you give some example?

Comment: True. I mentioned that the proper way would be to use constructors or extend class with Database class (or mysqli). I mean **class User extends Database{}** Sorry, english isn't my native language.

Comment: *class User extends Database* is indeed even bigger misunderstanding of OOP than using `global`...

Comment: As I said, using constructors (OOP way) is the proper way. These are options/examples how to include global $var inside the class. Or add $var that is outside the class.