# Simple onclick fails to redirect url

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm looking for some help.

I've got what should be a simple onclick redirect on a image.

I found some code (shown below) that assigns an onclick function to every image that uses the class thumbnails. For some reason its not allowing the url to redirect. I get no JS errors pop up but clearly something is failing...

```
$script .= "$(document).ready(function() {";
$script .= "$('img.thumbnail').click(function() {";
$script .= "window.location.href='".$href."'.replace(/__selected_service__/, selected_service);";
$script .= "});";
$script .= "});";

$s .= '<input type="radio" name="app_select_services" id="'.$service->ID.'" value="'.$service->ID.'"'.$sel.' /><label for="'.$service->ID.'"><img class="thumbnail" src="http://kerrymotorservices.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/'.$service->ID.'.png" title="'.$service_description.'"></label>';
```

Can anyone help please?

Comment: that is some nasty php right there....could you possibly show where all those other variables are coming from?

Comment: @deolectrix - Sorry, have a look at http://pastebin.com/D0Dc9N24 - thats the entire page. I'm editting a prewritten plugin but cannot understand why a button with a redirect works but an image onclick doesnt. Line 1203 is where I'm working :)

Comment: Can you post the js output for `window.location.href=` line

Comment: this is the location of the website: http://goo.gl/0VYvrE

I'll now get the output :)

Comment: `window.location.href=''.replace(/__selected_service__/, selected_service);` what's the purpose of `replace` ? Was there supposed to be an actual string before it, which at the moment seems to be empty? and `selected_service` doesn't seem to be a defined variable unless it was meant as a string?

Comment: oddly, when I echo $href it comes back blank and when I echo this code:
    "window.location.href='".$href."'.replace(/__selected_service__/, selected_service);";
it says: window.location.href=''.replace(/__selected_service__/, selected_service); so I'm assuming its not passing href however if I use the submit button it works... button code is line 1238

Comment: @samurai 
the url appends ?app_service_id=1 or ?app_service_id=2 depending on which radio button you select - in the php it checks to see if you have selected service 1 or 2.

If you look at the website now the button is shown and it now works if you click on either the car or van, it then redirects using the button...

Comment: And the click on the image should redirect exactly to the same url as the button? p.s. I changed its display and tested it already :p

Comment: @Samurai - Yes the image should be the same as the button, then I hide the button so they just click on the image...

Comment: See the answer, hopefully it'll work. Alternatively you could also make the button click fire on img.thumbnail click, so you didn't have to worry about other stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you use the `$href` before defining it (in the pastebin you posted you define $href like 50 lines later). So either move this bit of code after, or define $href earlier.

Secondly, in your button you're defining the variable `selected_service` which you're not doing it in your `click` for thumbnail img. So add the following line first line in your `click` function, so it should look like:

```
$script .= "<script>$(document).ready(function() {";
$script .= "$('img.thumbnail').click(function() {";
$script .= "var selected_service=$('input[type=radio][name=app_select_services]:checked').val();";
//...
```

Edit:
Alright changed the added line a little bit:

```
$script .= "var selected_service=$(this).parent().prev('input[type=radio][name=app_select_services]').val();";
```

Comment: Thank you, its almost worked... The images are now clickable, however the url doesnt change - no matter which image I click on, I get ?app_service_id=1

View http://pastebin.com/afPUnjng for the current code (I've moved the href above the click code you helped with! :)

Comment: I see some part of the script being echoed in the page, likely missed a closing syntax somewhere you just modified.

Comment: I added this in to the code to verify it was outputting ok

$outscript = "window.location.href='".$href."'.replace(/__selected_service__/, selected_service);";
    echo "href - ".$href."<br>";
    echo "script - ".$outscript."<br>";

Comment: Is this correct as above?

`   $script .= "$(document).ready(function() {";
    $script .= "$('img.thumbnail').click(function() {";
    $script .= "var selected_service=$('input[type=radio][name=app_select_services]:checked').val();";
    $script .= "window.location.href='".$href."'.replace(/__selected_service__/, selected_service);";
    $script .= "});";
    $script .= "});";`

I cannot add this as code :(

Comment: I've removed the echo code now, and the submit button but its still not assigning the selected service

Comment: Well the id is always 1 because at the moment we get it from `input[type=radio][name=app_select_services]:checked` which is always the one with id of 1 (they have display none as well). Do you want the id to be 2 when the right img is clicked if I understand correctly?

Comment: yes, if the left one is clicked it is 1, then if the right is clicked it is 2

Sorry, I thought the code was already doing that :(

Comment: Check the edit. (replace the new line with the old).

Comment: Sorry, its still not worked :(
If I view the website (so the url ends /mot-booking/ - with no ?app_ser.....)
when I click on the second image the service_id becomes undefined (check the url) and when I click on the first image, the service_id=2

Comment: No worries, change the next to prev (my bad, didn't look them properly). Edited the new line again.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I'm trying to add a variable to a JS function. http://pastebin.com/FasFfRhm - if you look at line 389 you'll see me setting a $vehicle variable. The echo works fine (see it on the main site first line on screen) however line 408 should then display that $vehicle but its blank.... Any ideas?

Comment: Well in line#389 you're defining a global variable, line#408 is in a class though and to be able to access that variable you need to use the keyword global. Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415577/accessing-variables-and-methods-outside-of-class-definitions

Comment: Of course!!! Ugh, missing the global... **Thank you (Again!!)**

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code on http://goo.gl/0VYvrE isn't surrounded by script tags.

Change to this:

```
$script .= "<script>$(document).ready(function() {";
$script .= "$('img.thumbnail').click(function() {";
$script .= "window.location.href='".$href."'.replace(/__selected_service__/, selected_service);";
$script .= "});";
$script .= "});</script>";
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion but that didn't work - I believe the $script is all appended to the other scripts and then added in to the footer.

If you view the source of the page you can see on line 373 where it builds the whole script in JS (I do note that $href seems to be empty all the time though...