# Access a variable inside a class from outside the class

Tags: php

I have a php class and variable as follows:

```
class Test(){
function fun(){
 $a= 0;
 $b = 5;
 $sum = $b+c;
 return sum;
}
}
```

I can access the `$sum` from outside as follows:

```
$obj = new Test();
echo $obj->fun();
```

How can I access the value of `$b` from outside class?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing variables and methods outside of class definitions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415577/accessing-variables-and-methods-outside-of-class-definitions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this scenario you can use Object properties,

Define a public variable inside your class,

```
class Test(){

    public $b;

    function fun(){
        $a= 0;
        $this->b = 5;
        $sum = $this->b+c;
        return $sum;
    }
}

$obj = new Test();
$b = $obj->b; // here null
echo $obj->fun();
$b = $obj->b; // here 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to make `$b` as a public datamember to be able to access it from outside

```
class Test() {
    public $b = 5;

    public function fun(){
        $a= 0;
        $sum = $this->b + c;

        return sum;
    }
}
```

Now you have access to `$b` by doing this

```
$obj = new Test();
echo $obj->b;
```