# Using function to create a connection

Tags: php, oop

I'm trying to create a connection using function in my other php file. So I can access it in every php file. How can I call the function inside my `class` from another php file. What is the proper way creating instance of my function will I put it in the top of my file or inside my class? I try to run my system but the connection won't load.

**connection.php**

```
<?php

DEFINE ('host', 'localhost');
DEFINE ('username', 'root');
DEFINE ('password', '');
DEFINE ('database', 'librarysystem');

function getConnection()
{
$myDB = mysqli_connect(host,username,password,database);

if (!$myDB)
{
    trigger_error ('Could not connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());
}
else
{
    return $myDB;
}
}                         
?>
```

Another file where I'm gonna call my function or method.

**loginCRUD.php**

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

require_once ('../connection/connection.php');

$myConnection = getConnection();

class loginCRUD
{
public function readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword)
{
    $statement = $myConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM loginmodule WHERE loginUsername = ? AND loginPassword = ? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param("ss", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    if($statement->execute())
    {
        $result = $statement->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows)
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
            return $row;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
}
(new loginCRUD)->readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword);
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$myDatabase` on the line where you define your statement just be `$myConnection`?

Comment: Pass `$myConnection` as an argument to a constructor for example.

Comment: `error_reporting(0);` why?

Comment: @gre_gor What the eye does not see, the developer does not have to fix _hehehhe_ So annoying I agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be at least two possible ways of passing `$myConnection` to your `loginCRUD` class.

**First** is to create `$myConnection` in a class itself:

```
class loginCRUD
{
    protected $dbCon;

    public function __construct() 
    {
       $this->dbCon = getConnection();
    }

    public function readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword)
    {
        $statement = $this->dbCon->prepare("YOUR SQL")
        // other codes
    }
}

(new loginCRUD)->readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword);
```

**Second** is to pass `$myConnection` as an argument to your class constructor:

```
class loginCRUD
{
    protected $dbCon;    

    public function __construct($myCon) 
    {
       $this->dbCon = $myCon;
    }

    public function readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword)
    {
        $statement = $this->dbCon->prepare("YOUR SQL")
        // other codes

    }
}

$myConnection = getConnection();
(new loginCRUD($myConnection))->readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword);
```

Comment: I prefer your first example! So glad you help :)

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an error is due to your **variable scope**. In your `loginCRUD`class you try to access a variable called `myConnection`, it fails to find it because the scope of the function is only that function. It doesn't know that you mean the **global** declared variable. A correct way of fixing this should be:

```
...
public function readLogin($dbusername,$dbpassword)
{
    global $myConnection;
    $statement = $myConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM loginmodule WHERE loginUsername = ? AND loginPassword = ? LIMIT 1");
    $statement->bind_param("ss", $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    if($statement->execute())
    {
...
```

For reference: [Accessing variables and methods outside of class definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1415577/accessing-variables-and-methods-outside-of-class-definitions)